# Linux cyclic DMA driver reading latest data first

Tags: linux-device-driver, dma

I'm quite new in driver development and I'm working on a driver for transferring data between custom hardware on a FPGA and an application running under Linux.

The DMA is continuously transferring fixed size chunks of data on a circular buffer. Into my "dma sync" callback (that is after each transfer), I put the buffer number into a (spinlocked) fifo. This fifo has the same number of elements as the number of DMA transfers in my circular buffer, therefore a buffer can't be twice in the FIFO (wouldn't make sense).

```
static void dma_sync_callback(void * callback_param) {
    struct fpgalogger_device * pd = (struct fpgalogger_device *)callback_param;
    unsigned int ret_val;
    static int previous_period_counter = 0;
    static int period_counter = 0;
    // Add indexes 0 to CYCLIC_DMA_PERIODS - 1 to the fifo

    if (period_counter == CYCLIC_DMA_PERIODS) {
        period_counter = 0;
    }
    if (period_counter != previous_period_counter) {
        if (kfifo_is_full( &(pd->fifo))) {
            unsigned int dummy;
            // Read out the oldest element in the fifo
            // Spinlock needed because possible
            // concurrent access in axi_dma_read
            kfifo_out_spinlocked( &(pd->fifo), &
                dummy,
                sizeof(dummy), &
                pd->kf_spinlock);
                
            // Put the new previous_period_counter
            // value into the fifo
            ret_val = kfifo_in( &(pd->fifo), &
                previous_period_counter,
                sizeof(previous_period_counter));
        } else {
            ret_val = kfifo_in( &(pd->fifo), &
                previous_period_counter,
                sizeof(previous_period_counter));
            // Perform semaphore up
            up( &pd->sema);
        }
    }

    previous_period_counter = period_counter;
    ++period_counter;
}
```

In my character driver's read function, I take elements from the fifo to know which buffer to read, and copy the content of that buffer to the user.

```
static int logger_read(struct file * filp, char * buf, size_t cnt, loff_t * f_pos) {
    // Inits and various checks ...
        [...]

    // Wait for data
    ret_val = down_timeout( &pd->sema, 1 * HZ);
    if (ret_val) {
        return -ENODATA;
    }

    // Sanity check
    if (kfifo_is_empty( & pd->fifo)) {
        return -EBADFD;
    }
 
    // Get last element
    ret_val = kfifo_out_spinlocked( & pd->fifo, &index,
        sizeof(index), &
        pd->kf_spinlock);
    if (ret_val != sizeof(index)) {
        return -EBADFD;
    }

    // Safely copy to user
    dma_sync_single_for_cpu(pd -> rx_chan -> device -> dev,
        pd->rx_dma_handle + (index * pd->transfer_size),
        pd->transfer_size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
    ret_val = copy_to_user(buf, &
        pd->dest_dma_buffer[period_index * pd->transfer_size],
        cnt);
    dma_sync_single_for_device(pd -> rx_chan -> device -> dev,
        pd->rx_dma_handle + (index * pd->transfer_size),
        pd->transfer_size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

It globally works with one exception: when read is called as the FIFO is full, the first data I get is the latest one, potentially still being written by the DMA. I can "feel" what happens there. When the FIFO is full, the next buffer to write is also the oldest, due to the circular nature of the buffer.

Is there anything I can do against this? Or is the way I handle my DMA just not right?

Thanks in advance for all your support.

Comment: Can you make the hardware flag an "overrun" error instead of overwriting the unread buffer?

Comment: Usually the circular buffer size is twice bigger than the maximum chunk size. And DNA thresholds are halves of the (hardware) FIFO sizes.